# Id of a model is not passed from the view to the action correctly in ASP MVC when Editing a list of models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm passing a list of objects to a view and allow the user to update a property of a single object.

This is the get action. I'm passing a list of Articles to the view here.

```
public ActionResult EditArticleList(int id)
    {
        ArticleList articleList = unitOfWork.ArticleListRepository.GetById(id);
        IEnumerable<Article> Articles = articleList.Articles;

        return View(Articles);
    }
```

This is the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Article>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EditArticleList</title>
</head>
<body>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("EditArticleList", "AdminArticleList", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ToList()[i].Title, null, "Title")
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ToList()[i].Id)

    <input type="submit" />
    <br />
    }
}
```

This is the post action.

```
public ActionResult EditArticleList(Article art)
    {
    }
```

I'm passing 3 articles with Ids of 1,2,3.
But no matter which Article I update and post, the id is returned as 1.
The title is returned correctly.

Comment: This really makes no sense. Your can only submit one form at a time so why are you creating multiple forms. And your generating `name` attributes that do not relate to your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm allowing the user to update one item at one time from a list of items. Each item has an update button. That's why I'm creating one form for each item.

Comment: That is the wrong approach and is an awful UI (what if the user enters values in 2 textboxes and hits a submit button thinking that both will be saved. And you would not be able to return the view if `ModelState` was invalid

Comment: Either have a readonly 'Index' view with an 'Edit' link or one forn with a `for` loop so that the user can edit them all in one action

Answer (score 0):

This works, and better than a mvc only solution, which would require each button to have an id on it.  Can you please let me if you want me to research a querystring pure mvc solution?:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Testy20161006.Controllers.Article>
@using Testy20161006.Controllers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EditArticleList</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SubmitTheForm(theId) {
            $("#theId").val(theId);
            $("#formName").submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @*USE YOUR own controller below*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditArticleList", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formName" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="theId" name="theId" />
        <table>
            @foreach (Article item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Title, null, "Title")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" onclick="SubmitTheForm('@item.Id')" value="Select" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <br />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller/View Model:

```
//your code might be slightly different, but if you look at the view you can solve your issue
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleList
{
    public IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

namespace unitOfWork
{
    public static class ArticleListRepository
    {
        public static ArticleList GetById(int id)
        {
            var article1 = new Article { Id = 1, Title = "article1" };
            var article2 = new Article { Id = 2, Title = "article2" };
            var article3 = new Article { Id = 3, Title = "article3" };
            ArticleList articleList = new ArticleList();
            articleList.Articles = new List<Article>();
            articleList.Articles.Add(article1);
            articleList.Articles.Add(article2);
            articleList.Articles.Add(article3);
            return articleList;
        }
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditArticleList(int theId, Article art)
    {
        //put breakpoint here to see the id returned.
        return View(art);
    }

    public ActionResult EditArticleList(int? id)
    {
        ArticleList articleList = unitOfWork.ArticleListRepository.GetById(5);  //hard coding for demo
        IEnumerable<Article> Articles = articleList.Articles;

        return View(Articles);
    }
```